# Getting the title using urllib

Tags: python, urllib

I am supposed to write a code that goes into a web site and gets its title so here is the code i have

```
import urllib.request
def findTitle(url):
    urllib.request.Request(url)
    #open url
    urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
    #set same variable equal to the end of <title> tag
    endTitlePos = url.find("<title>")
    #set variable equal to starting position of <title> tag
    startTitlePos  = url.find("<title>", endTitlePos)
    startTitlePos += len("<title>")
    #set new variable equal to </title>
    TitleContent=url.find("</title>",startTitlePos)
    #return slice of output between the two variables
    title = url[startTitlePos:endTitlePos]
    content_list=[]
    content_list.append(title)
    return content_list
def main():
    url="https://google.com/search"
    print(findTitle(url))
```

main()

we are using google for an example. Now its supposed to just print "google" but currently it prints "['//google.com/searc']" i am just curious what i am missing here, i mean it seems very simple but i dont know why its printing the url rather then the title and how also do i turn it form the list into a string?

Answer (score 4):

There are several alternative to get data from webpages. The best use BeautifulSoup. In your case string split() method works well

```
import urllib.request

def findTitle(url):
    webpage = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    title = str(webpage).split('<title>')[1].split('</title>')[0]
    return title

>>>print(findTitle('http://www.google.com'))
Google
```

Comment: I see how this method would work, and thank you very much. I am curious what exactly they were getting at with using the skeleton they gave us. I mean I am asking why didnt my code find the actual title? it seems to have just tracked down the url and then displayed it.

Comment: In your code just change 3 statement to urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()